# Get Video Information from ChannelD

Tags: youtube-api, google-api

I am looking for the json from where i can get information of video falls in specific channel(ChannelId is given). I tried below to get the same, but page not found showing.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=***&channelId=UC39dDX5cE3WxN5ObmCBsCCQ
```

Or any other effective way to fetch the information?

Answer (score 0):

Api version 3 returns only json in responses. You find information at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Channel information returns a playlist-id of the uploaded videos for a channel.

But using search can work too (Replace YourApiKey with your own key):
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&channelId=UC39dDX5cE3WxN5ObmCBsCCQ&maxResults=50&key=YourApiKey